# Getting Cents from Math C++

Tags: c++

Right now my code works just that when I get I print out he cents i am off by one because of the the round error the compiler does when you take say 0.95 * 100 it gives me 94 or something that is not 95. I know how the math works to get it normally but with this rounding error I can't do it.

Also don't worry about asking me why I am using C and C++ at the same time. Its because this is how my instructor wanted it.

Here is the relevant code.

```
if (dollarAmount < 10.00 && dollarAmount >= 1.00)
{
    cents = (dollarAmount - static_cast<int>(dollarAmount)) * 100;
    digit = (((static_cast<int>(dollarAmount)/ 1)));

    strcat(amountInWords, lookUp[digit]);
    strcat(amountInWords, " dollars and ");

}
```

Whole project code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/65c052277c67f03de643

Comment: Floating point numbers are prone to errors of precision. Don't store currency values as dollars - store as cents and use integers for arithmetic, then convert to dollars for display.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use floating point variables when rounding is important.
Just use a long variable to store cents.

Comment: What do you mean? Cents is an integer. I have dollar amounts stored as a double.

Comment: Yes, people mostly default to using floating point whenever they see a decimal point. However, the key strength of floating point format is that the decimal point can effectively _float_ with changing magnitude, not simply that it has a decimal point. The floating behaviour has significant drawbacks such as rounding precision. If you know the magnitude ahead of time, it is often better to use more natural units such that the smallest quantity is 1 (eg, use cents instead of dollars), and then stick with integers.

Comment: Instead of saying something like `double dollarAmount = 3.14`, say instead `long centAmount = 314`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`round()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/round/) instead of `static_cast<int>`. The difference between the actual value and what fits inside your float is 0.0000000somethingsmall. Rounding will always give the correct answer.

Also, round only **after** multiplying by 100.

Comment: Round still doesn't do what I want. Can you give me an example of what you mean? Because I looked at the reference for that function and it rounds to the nearest whole number and if my amount is 153.66 I will get a negitive number if I do amount - round(amound) * 100; I also looked at truncate and its doing the same thing.

Comment: @TheMrDrake - still, @Christoph is right. Using a `long amountInCents;` would be better. Unless you actually need fractional cents.